# Azure DevOps dotnet ef migrations script command running slow

Tags: azure-devops

I have two DBContext in the same solution. When I run the EF migration command for any of the DBContext locally it executes successfully in under 30 secs.

```
 dotnet ef migrations script -s $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyProject.Web/ --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\myproject-DBScript-$(build.SourceBranchName)\$(build.SourceBranchName)-migrationScript.sql --context DBContext  --idempotent
```

But when I run the same command as part of azure build it takes anywhere between 7 to 15 minutes. Please note I can see the build logs, it is the actual command which is taking longer and not the agent availability or any tool like dotnet download issue. The build agent is windows with Vs2017.

Why the timeline is different for local and Azure-Devops, is something wrong with the above command or is it the normal time for an EF migration to run on Azure-Devops. [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f16c.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

A Microsoft-hosted agent can take longer to start your build. While it often takes just a few seconds for your job to be assigned to a Microsoft-hosted agent, it can sometimes take several minutes for an agent to be allocated depending on the load on our system.

If Microsoft-hosted agents don't meet your needs, as a workaround you can [deploy your own self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install). Self-hosted agents give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.

Potential performance advantages that you might get by using self-hosted agents which might start and run builds faster. For details ,please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#private-agent-performance-advantages).

Comment: I am ok if it just not started the job at all but as I said above that this doesn't look like the agent availability issue. From logs, I can see the job assignment to agent, prepare job, initialize job and checkout all are really quick. I can even see the message I am printing (echo) just before executing EF command and also the messages like welcome to .Net core all appearing really quickly but it always stuck at "Successfully installed the ASP.NET Core HTTPS Development Certificate.". For reference I have added the log in my post.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.You can try to use the private agent to see if it is also slow.It may also be the reason for the slow network.